# ReferenceError: prefix is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im programming a discord bot, and have been implementing a Ban command: Starting the bot works fine, but as soon as i run '/ban', i get an error in console. Any fix?
Code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    description: "Bans a member from the server",
    execute(message) {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!');
        if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the right permissions.');
        
        const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

        if (!args[0]) {
            return message.channel.send('Please specify a user!');
        }
        if (!member) {
            return message.channel.send('Cant find that user');
        }
        if (!member.bannable) {
            return message.channel.send('Cant ban that user');
        }
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if (!reason) {
            reason = 'Unspecified';
        }
        member.ban({ days: 7, reason: '${reason}' }).catch(err => { 
            message.channel.send('Something went wrong');
              console.log(err);
          });
        
        const banembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Member Banned')
          .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .addField('User Banned', member)
          .addField('Kicked by', message.author)
          .addField('Reason', reason)
          .setFooter('Time kicked', client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setTimestamp();
  
          message.channel.send(banembed);
        }
    };
```

And here's the error:

```
ReferenceError: args is not defined
at Object.execute (C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Projects\Vatox-BOT\commands\ban2.js:8:92)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Projects\Vatox-BOT\index.js:67:11)
at Client.emit (node:events:327:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Projects\Vatox-BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Projects\Vatox-BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Projects\Vatox-BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Projects\Vatox-BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Projects\Vatox-BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\aweso\Documents\Projects\Vatox-BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:327:20)
```

I know the obvious fix is to define 'args', but this is executed from Index.js which has already defined args.

Comment: Variables don't carry over from file to file. You need to pass the `args` array to the `execute` function in your command handler.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the args here, and inside your parentesis in your index.js:
execute(message, args)

Comment: Welcome to SOF, please comment one-line answers, thanks